# How to bind the different item sources for child grid?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, nested-table

I need to bind the different number of columns for child grid which associated with each parent row like as below

```
Name        Address 
+ Jack      Email
    Category    Email
    Work        Jack.123@gmail.com
    Personal    Jk@yahoo.com
+ Bruce Street Address
    Category    StreetCity      Zip
    Work        123 Main St     Anytown 44444
    Home        123 Peach St    Anytown 44456
```

Is it possible to achieve this in grid . If it is possible please share the code part.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856662/c-sharp-data-table-to-hold-tables-infinite-nesting

Comment: If i use the datatable for Column which bound the datatable properties in childgrid.Is it possible to handle this? Code part  gridDataList.Add(new Sale("1", "110", new List<DataTable>() { dt}));

Comment: i don't see why it wouldn't be possible...